If $T : L^p(D) \rightarrow X$ has operator norms $C_p$ that converge to $C_1$, what is the operator norm of $T : L^1(D) \rightarrow X$?
For any domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, we consider the Lebesgue space $L^p(D)$ with exponent $1 \leq p < \infty$.
Let $X$ be some Hilbert space and suppose that $T : L^p(D) \rightarrow X$ is a bounded operator defined for all Lebesgue spaces with $p \geq 1$.
Let's assume that I already have got upper bounds for the operator norms $\| T \|_{L^p(D) \rightarrow X} \leq C_p$ for all $p > 1$ and that $$ \lim_{ p \rightarrow 1 } C_p =C_1$$ for some constant $C_1$.
Does it follow that $\| T \|_{L^1(D) \rightarrow X} \leq C_1$ ?

Let $\phi (x) := \min(1, \exp(-|x|))$. Then $\phi \in L^p(D)$ for all $p$ and $\phi(x)>0$ for all $x$. (Here we need only the existence of $\phi\in L^1 \cap L^\infty$ that is positive a.e., so the argument should go through for general $\sigma$-finite measure space.)
Take $ u \in L^1(D)$. Then
$$
u_n := \min(-n \phi, \max( u, +n \phi))
$$
belongs to all $L^p$ for all $n$.
By dominated convergence $u_n \to u$ in $L^1(D)$.
Then
$$
\| Tu \|_X = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|Tu_n\|_X
$$
and
$$
 \|Tu_n\|_X \le C_p \|u_n\|_{L^p(D)}.
$$
On the right-hand side, we can pass to the limit $p\searrow1$ by dominated convergence to get
$$
 \|Tu_n\|_X \le C_1 \|u_n\|_{L^1(D)}.
$$
The right-hand side converges to $C_1 \|u\|_{L^1(D)}$, which proves the claim.

Thank you. Is there a specific reason you pick this function? It seems that you that the "operator norm inequality" holds for some specific function.

No special reason: this proves needs that $\phi$ belongs to $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ (hence to all $L^p$) and is positive a.e.
